# Mac(os x): Is there a way to install ONLY redis-cli?

Tags: macos, redis

I tried to run `brew install redis-cli` and googled, but found nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: `brew install redis` only installs 6 files as it is - and one of them is a symlink!

Comment: My console says: `/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.0: 10 files 1.7M`:) But actually, no matter I just didn't notice that it doesn't run a redis service by default. If you add your comment as an answer(with some details), I'll accept it

Comment: Sadly seems no. I also looking for the same thing

Answer (score 188, accepted):

If you install **redis** with **homebrew**, you can see what's in the package like this:

```
brew install redis
brew ls redis
```

You will see that it only installs very few files indeed anyway:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin/redis-benchmark
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin/redis-check-aof
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin/redis-check-rdb
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin/redis-cli
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin/redis-sentinel
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin/redis-server
/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Or, you can look directly in `homebrew`'s Cellar, like this:

```
ls -lR /usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  admin  1487  2 Aug 10:00 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  admin   376  9 Aug 10:34 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  admin  6834  2 Aug 10:00 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  8 mark  admin   272  2 Aug 10:00 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  admin   785  9 Aug 10:34 homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist

/usr/local/Cellar/redis/3.2.3/bin:
total 3440
-r-xr-xr-x  1 mark  admin   67668  2 Aug 10:00 redis-benchmark
-r-xr-xr-x  1 mark  admin   13936  2 Aug 10:00 redis-check-aof
-r-xr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  768704  2 Aug 10:00 redis-check-rdb
-r-xr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  129712  2 Aug 10:00 redis-cli
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin      12  2 Aug 10:00 redis-sentinel -> redis-server
-r-xr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  768704  2 Aug 10:00 redis-server
```

So, a lot of it is the licence, README and, of the 6 binaries, one is a symlink anyway. So it is not a heavy-weight installation with loads of services and config files anyway.

---

By the way, you could always pull and run the **docker** `redis-cli` without installing anything:

```
docker run --rm -it redis:alpine redis-cli -h 192.168.0.8     # change to your Redis host's IP
```

---

If you actually just want to install the very least software you possibly can, you don't actually have to install anything! The Redis protocol is pretty simple, so you can build up a command in `bash` and send it yourself like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# redis.sh
# Very, very simplistic Redis client in bash
# Mark Setchell
# Usage:
# redis.sh SET answer 42
#
# Ref: https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert
################################################################################
if [ $# -lt 2 ] ; then
    echo "Usage: redis.sh SET answer 42" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Build protocol string
protocol="*$#\r\n"

for var in "$@" ; do
   protocol+="$" 
   protocol+="${#var}\r\n${var}\r\n"
done

# Send to Redis on default port on local host - but you can change it
printf "$protocol" > /dev/tcp/localhost/6379
```

Comment: to run this you first need to install redis otherwise it will give you error  like this
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/redis
to install just run "brew install redis"
Then run "brew ls redis"

Comment: In my case, showing -  `brew ls redis -> 
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/redis`

Comment: @SandeepanNath `brew ls` only shows you what was installed. you have to first `brew install redis` to see it

Comment: Getting 'Error: No available formula with the name "redis-cli"' in 2020 as well.

Comment: @realPK I didn't suggest any formula with the name `redis-cli` so you cannot have got that message from running my suggested answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Don't remember what triggered this error message but I simply pasted what I saw on terminal. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Very simple protocol indeed. As a bonus on your shell script, if you want to talk to any Redis host, replace the last line with
`printf "$protocol" | nc <redis host> 6379  -v`
Replace `<redis host>`. Can easily modify the script to accept host as input argument too. Read the manual of `nc` for more details in this very useful Transport Layer network command.

Answer (score 180):

```
brew tap ringohub/redis-cli

brew update && brew doctor

brew install redis-cli
```

Comment: This is the only answer that properly answers the question and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Who/what is "ringohub" and why should I install software from it?

Comment: I'm not getting the latest version of redis-cli with this

Comment: Any way to get  @kharandziuk to accept this answer? I understand that this question is three years old, but still...

Comment: I agree with Henrik, for security reasons we should not install packages from unknown sources. But still, I upvote this answer. It was the most helpful for me.

Comment: Agree with @Henrik, this is an unknown source. I would mark this as the accepted answer if it was from a reliable source

Comment: You can view the contents of the package with `brew info redis-cli` which references https://github.com/aoki/homebrew-redis-cli/blob/HEAD/redis-cli.rb which is installing official code from github.com/antirez/redis

Answer (score 38):

This is not a proper installation of redis-cli, BUt I get my work done. 
I get it working using npm, I installed [redis-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-cli) a javascript library.

```
$ npm install -g redis-cli                  
    /Users/toni/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/rdcli -> /Users/toni/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/redis-cli/bin/rdcli
    + redis-cli@1.3.0
    updated 1 package in 1.07s
```

then using the console:

```
$ rdcli                                 
127.0.0.1:6379> keys incident::sequence
1) incident::sequence
127.0.0.1:6379> GET incident::sequence
570
127.0.0.1:6379> config get dir
1) dir
2) /data
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

Comment: This is actually how Redislabs suggest doing it on there website -https://redislabs.com/blog/get-redis-cli-without-installing-redis-server/

Comment: Warning!: I have been using rdcli for a while however just realized it doesn't support full functionality. For instance, I tried to execute "Memory Stats" it was giving an error saying "elem.map is not a function". After switching to native redis-cli, it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I installed the redis-cli nodejs module:

```
yarn global add redis-cli
```

Then ran redis client:

```
rdcli
```

and redis client connected, redis REPL shell was activated

Answer (score 2):

You can use `telnet [host [port]]` to connect to redis:

```
telnet localhost 6379
```

Answer (score 2):

- Download latest version from https://github.com/redis/redis-hashes
- Unpack tha archive
- Run redis-cli from your $PATH

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if redis is installed or not. Command-
telnet localhost 6379

if not then you can add it with brew or yarn.

for Yarn- yarn global add redis-cli
for brew- brew install redis
for NPM- $npm install -g redis-cli