# UNIX - Can process communicate with another process by using bash program?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process, communication

I'm having a discussion with my Operating Systems teacher about whether shell program can be used to communicate with another process. He says it can't while I believe it actually can.

For example: if we write *echo "123" >> file.txt*, and there is a process named P1 that reads data from this file, isn't it communication between those two processes?

Another example: There is a process P1 that waits for a file to be created in order to proceed. If we create that file by using *touch file.txt*, isn't it also considered as communication?

Is my teacher really right? If so, could someone please explain to me why? He gave me some examples about how can a process communicate with one another, such as: shared memory area, pipes or signals.

Comment: who is going to mark your exam - us or your operating systems teacher?   I would put it in the "not what people traditionally mean when they say communication" basket.  Having said that "touch files" are a heuristic I use all the time.

Comment: @MrR you see, the thing is... this exam was already marked by my OS teacher and I failed it. I'am literally 0.1% away from passing it and in order to get the additional 0.1%, I have to explain why shell program can not communicate with another process.

I know the question is tricky and that it can be interpreted in so many ways, but every single sight could matter big time for me. When I read about IPC, there also was nothing about shell programms and I wonder why.

Comment: Normally it isn't the shell connecting to the other process, it sets up the communications but isn't doing the communication.  e.g. `cat file | programUsingFile`  .. the shell links them up but they are doing the communication .. OR you have something running in the shell connecting to a remote process.   For instance TCL or Expect allow you to do interactive dialogs (say to do password entry on login)..

Comment: So if you run `netcat` in one Terminal like this `nc -u -l 3000` and in another Terminal/process you run this `echo "Told you so" > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/3000` You should become an A* pupil ;-)

Comment: Maybe also ask what `coproc` is, if it isn't *'Inter-process Communication"* https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html

Comment: You can also read and write a **Redis** instance from `bash` and thereby communicate with any other person/process in the world that has access to that instance. See last part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706850/2836621

Comment: You can also turn on/off an LED (if on a Raspberry Pi), play a piece of music or make a beep (`tput bel`), or power off the machine which will all potentially *"communicate"* something to any person or process that is looking or listening...

Comment: Thanks so much guys for your effort. It helped me a lot. Especially @MrR second answer. I managed to pass the exam!